# Move first row of a HTML table under a thead tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, birt

I have a html table generated by BIRT as follow:

```
<table id="myTableID">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to write a JavaScript code that reads this table and re-writes it in the following form: getting the first row of the table in a `<thead>` tag, and the rest of the table in the `<tbody>` tag:

```
<table id="myTableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I have a basic knowledge about the JavaScript, but I have no clue how to proceed with such case. Please any help?

Comment: `$('#myTableID tr:first').wrap('<thead />')`

Comment: Basically `th` is for `thead` and `td` is for `tbody`. Do you need `th` for tbody as well?

Comment: If `td` is OK then please let me know I'll post my answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use [**prependTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) to insert the `thead` element
2. Use [**append()**](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) to insert the first `tr` inside the `thead`

```js
$('<thead></thead>').prependTo('#myTableID').append($('#myTableID tr:first'));

console.log($('#myTableID')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTableID">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Dhoha, it is working if you run the snippet. Can you give me more detail on why it is not working so I can help? Can you reproduce the attemt in a http:jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sorry, I had another mistake that prevent me to see the results... It worked :)